# No result from chrome.tabs.query in Opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, opera, opera-extension

I have developed a [Chrome extension](https://github.com/xkeshav/colorme), it works fine in Chrome 39 but gives an error in Opera developer 24 on *Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit).*

> Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id'
>   of undefined  at HTMLLIElement.click

So I tested [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) on both browser consoles:

```
chrome.tabs.query(
  { active: true, highlighted: true, currentWindow: true }, 
  function(thisTab) {
    console.log(thisTab);
  }
);
```

In Chrome it returns a complete `Tab` object.

But in Opera it returns a blank array `[]`.

[image: screenshots]

Why this is happening?

Comment: also anyone can tell me "which action causes to display `undefined` in console just before the result of `console.log` in both browser?"

Comment: the first `undefined` is the return value of `chrome.tabs.query`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Opera does not include the concept of a highlighted tab, which is already pretty obscure in Chrome.

Your query is excessive anyway: in Chrome, the active tab cannot be non-highlighted.

So, for a query that works in both, use `{active: true, currentWindow: true}`.

Comment: Thank you once again for helping. console must gives proper error details instead of unidentified error. Isn't it?

Comment: No. It's just that there are no tabs with `highlighted: true`, so your filter returns an empty result. I guess the property itself is valid for backwards compatibility, so no explicit error.

Comment: I'm finding that **chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}** is always returning 0 length array in chrome, any ideas?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper I'm guessing https://stackoverflow.com/a/29683574/934239