# Background script messaging with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, communication

I was messing around with communicating inside a Google Chrome extension and was using the following guide: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging

It used to work but I have encountered an error :

> Error in response to tabs.query: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id'
>   of undefined

I compared my code and the Google Chrome code and I can't seem to find why my code produces that error:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[1].id, {fen: request.needMove}, function(response) {
                    //console.log(response.farewell);
                });
            });
```

Here is where I send it to:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("recv FEN : " + FEN);
   FEN = request.fen;
   setCookie("FEN_SET", "true" , 1);
   setFEN(FEN);

  });
```

I can't fix that error, whatever I try it stays the same.
"Cannot read property of undefined" is implying that 'tabs' is undefined as far as I understood but I don't understand why it works in the Google example and here it doesn't.

**Another Q :**

If I'm trying to send it to tabs[1] does that mean it's the tab in the second position, or am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: Without being familiar with the platform, the error means `tabs[1]` is undefined, debug the script at that point and see what the actual contents of `tabs` are.

Comment: says : "tabs: Array[0]" but if you look a the google example , its exactly the same I copied and pasted it to fit my needs

Comment: Make sure you have at least two tabs open in the browser

Comment: I have more than that , my extension requires two pages...

Comment: If tabs is Array[0] then `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},...)` is returning an empty array. Try broadening your query so it returns all the tabs you are looking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`tabs` is the list of all tabs (regardless of position) that pass the filter.

Your query is `{active: true, currentWindow: true}`, so normally it should be just 1 tab (as there is at most 1 current window with exactly 1 active tab).

So you need the first element, which is `tabs[0]`.

`tabs[1]` will always be undefined with this query.

---

Cases when `tabs` will be empty empty used to be exceedingly rare (Chrome running in background with no windows open).

However, **with a recent change the API will not return the Dev Tools tab**. So if you're debugging your extension and the Dev Tools window is open and focused, the array will be empty. You should check for that.

Comment: How do i select all tabs?

Comment: Empty query? `{}` Read the docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query

Comment: Final note that position within a window is indicated by `index` property of the tab, not the position in the array returned. If you want "second tab" you'll need to search for index or better yet include it in the query.

Comment: @Xan, could you be a bit more explicit on what a valid workaround would be for debugging? When the DevTools tab is open, tabs return []. How would you check for that and work through?

Comment: @Ovi If you need to trigger code that relies on `query` from the Dev Tools, I would wrap it with a `setTimeout` with a couple of seconds of delay and switch to an actual window. And in general it's more robust to check that `tabs.length` is positive before proceeding with accessing `tabs[0]` - it shouldn't normally happen but can happen if you're debugging or Chrome is running without active windows (e.g. a Chrome App is open but the browser is closed) and you should react accordingly.

Comment: "However, with a recent change the API will not return the Dev Tools tab. So if you're debugging your extension and the Dev Tools window is open and focused, the array will be empty. You should check for that." - very good to know

Comment: {active: true, currentWindow: true} always gives me back Array of length 0, even on a non devTools tab

Comment: actually if you remove all the background tabs it works